# Replace one button with other in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to replace an active button with deactivate button but clicking on the active button replaces it with deactive button but on clicking again it does change to active. I am stuck here in this.

```
<td class="statusButtons">
         <span><a href="#" class='status activeBtn'>Active</a></span>&nbsp;
         <span><a href="#" class='status editBtn'>Edit</a></span>&nbsp;
         <span><a href="#" class='status deleteBtn'>Delete</a></span>
 </td>
```

the JavaScript code is

```
const statusButtons=document.querySelector(".statusButtons");
const status=document.querySelector(".status");
const activeBtn=document.querySelector(".activeBtn");
activeBtn.addEventListener("click",changeA2D);
function changeA2D(){
    activeBtn.style.visiblity='hidden';
    activeBtn.parentElement.innerHTML=`<a href="#" class='status deactiveBtn'>Deactive</a>`;
}
```

Comment: Leaving aside that this approach is not ideal, you're never assigning a click listener to the new button.

Comment: Chris G how can I assign click listener a new button?

Comment: Here's a better approach: https://jsfiddle.net/smuL710y/ (hide/display buttons based on row class, use buttons to add/remove row class)

Comment: Chris G thank you so much for this approach it worked for me too trying to understand the code :)))

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change the element, Just the text in it according to the `isActive` state.

```js
const statusButtons = document.querySelector(".statusButtons");
const status = document.querySelector(".status");
const activeBtn = document.querySelector(".activeBtn");
activeBtn.addEventListener("click", changeA2D);

let isActive = true;

function changeA2D() {
    isActive = !isActive
    activeBtn.innerText = isActive ? 'Active' : 'Deactive';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add an id to the ActiveBtn for better selecting when using document.querySelector()

```
<td class="statusButtons">
         <span><a href="#" class='status activeBtn' id ='statusTrigger'>Active</a></span>&nbsp;
         <span><a href="#" class='status editBtn'>Edit</a></span>&nbsp;
         <span><a href="#" class='status deleteBtn'>Delete</a></span>
    </td>
```

And then I will use the following code to toggle the btn

```
let statusTrigger = document.querySelector("#statusTrigger");
statusTrigger.addEventListener("click", changeA2D);
function changeA2D() {
    statusTrigger.classList.toggle("activeBtn");
    statusTrigger.classList.toggle("deactiveBtn")
    let btnText = statusTrigger.classList.contains("activeBtn")?"Active":"Deactive"
    statusTrigger.innerText = btnText;
}
```

Dor Ben Itzhak answer forget to change the class when pressed